# Share Eclipse Workspace on GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, github

I want to build my portfolio on GitHub. I have a few Java projects and I used Eclipse to build them. How should I share them on GitHub?

1. Should I share only the `src` folder? That way, however, I would end up losing some dependencies (databases or img folder etc.).
2. Is it good practice to share the Eclipse workspace on GitHub? If I use third party libraries these will be included too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <s>Sharing only the bin folder would be mostly pointless. Basically, if you want to share your projects in Github, the expectation is that you are also sharing your source code as well.</s> Sharing only the src folder would still be mainly pointless, both for the missing resources you already mentioned and also for missing project metadata (e.g. required Java version, project name, etc.) that gets stored there. Without this metadata it might be still possible to compile your projects, but having the project metadata included allows others to simply check it out into an Eclipse instance, and it should compile and run without any extra configuration required.
2. Sharing a workspace is a bad idea, as your workspace .metadata folder contains your preference settings, file system references (sometimes referring to absolute paths on your computer), and sometimes even passwords. I would not recommend doing it.

To be more constructive, I would suggest to do the following:

1. Categorize your projects, and create a separate repository for each different project. This helps to show you are building several things that can be used separately. Of course, if some projects belong together, share them inside a common repository.
2. When you create a repository, generate a gitignore file related your project type (e.g. Java project) - see screenshot below. This sets up the repository in a way that you are not uploading class files, etc. that is unnecessary in a source code repository.
3. Share your projects one-by-one into this repository. Eclipse has the [EGit project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) that supports this aspect (most likely it is already installed if you have a not too old Eclipse instance.

[image: gitignore settings]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant the `src` folder, not `bin`. I corrected my question.

Comment: @MarcoGreselin I have updated the answer to take account this change; however, it did not change my recommendation greatly.

Comment: thnaks. I did like you said but when I download the repo and open it in Eclipse it gives me an error message: "Error: Could not find or load main class main.MainClass" because it's missing the compiled files. How can I solve this in Eclipse?

Comment: @MarcoGreselin In general, it should work. The only potential issue I can see is that you have turned off automatic builds, in which case you should compile manually (or maybe there are some compile errors).